# Is Bind(Include = "","",etc) necessary

Tags: asp.net-mvc

By default when I create a controller with the CRUD ActionResults using Entity Framework, they look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID, Property1, Property2")] ClassName object)
{
    // do whatever
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID, Property1, Property2")] ClassName object)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Is the `[Bind(Include = "ID, Property1, Property2")]` necessary?  Why can't I just do this?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ClassName object)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary, unless you care about security :-)  By the same token, the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute is also not necessary.

Comment: Your editing data so you should be using a view model, in which case `[Bind]` is irrelevant because you already protected against over-posting attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely do it without the Bind, but note that it will expose the Edit function to potential parameter injection. For clarity, let's say that you are passing in a class, Foo, and Foo has additional properties, like Property3 and Property4, then by not restricting the method with the Bind, the method will allow and accept values for these additional properties, which may not be what you wanted/intended.

TL;DR: The Bind is not necessary.